# Border problems in chrome

Tags: css, less, border

I'm having a problem with a fixed border around a responsively sized div. This issue only happens in Chrome.

I'm having a hard time reproducing it in JSFiddle, but I'm essentially trying to center a div within another (which is placed somewhere on my page) and the centered-div has a nice 1px border around it. The LESS for these two elements are as follows:

```
.popup {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 93%; width: 30%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-left: -3%;
    position: relative;

    .text {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%; height: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 5%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%; left: 50%;
        .translate(-50%, -50%); # Some LESS that is just a translate call
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

This is what I see, which changes as the screen size changes (sometimes correct, sometimes different borders are missing/incorrect):

[image: Borders missing!]
[image: Borders are inconsistent]

EDIT: Added relevant HTML.

```
<div class="container">
    ...Other stuff...
    <div class="content">
        ...Other stuff...
        <div class="breakdown">
            <div class="block">C++ (Circle dials you see)</div>
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="text">Some text here to go in the popup</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">Java (Next dial)</div>
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="text">Some text here to go in the popup for the Java dial</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's more stuff in container, and more stuff in content in the DOM levels shown. However, the other items in container are each in their own block on the page (no overlap), and so is the items in content. A breakdown div holds the dials and popups that you can see in the screenshots. The idea is that when i hover over a "block" or a dial the popup shows up to the right, shoving the next dial over when shown.

Comment: make sure that no other element overlaps your border. Try to set a `z-index` for the `.popup` class. I think that you also have to post your html, to get better answers

Comment: Added some HTML that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed such issues with borders when I have zoomed the page - that would explain why you see it only in Chrome and only on one domain (you said you cannot reproduce it in JSFiddle).

Click Ctrl+0 or check if you have an icon in the addressbar of a magnifying glass (it's displayed when the zoom level is different from 100%).

Comment: Nope, no zoom. Its difficult since it is placed in a decently sized dom tree, so maybe something is messing it up. But I was under the impression that the rendering engine appropriately encapsulates the positioning logic. The bug seems to not appear in firefox or safari or even IE

Comment: Hmmm, then you need to investigate the css further, the only other possible thing I can think of is if a parent element has a -webkit-transform: scale(), but then it would occur in safari as well... It's impossible to help without looking at the code.

Comment: There are transform translates as you see above. I guess I'll keep messing around. As of now i can just slowly untick properties until it magically works.